# Evitar refrescar pagina cuando se valida el formulario con jqueryvalidation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

Hola buenas tardes estoy validando un formulario con jqueryvalidation pero cuando mis campos están llenos correctamente me refresca la pagina y no se como evitar que se refresque la página, de tener esta liga http://localhost/IntranetUCQ/Tickets me cambia a esta http://localhost/IntranetUCQ/Tickets?date-inicio=2020%2F06%2F01&date-fin=2020%2F06%2F01#
, analice que es por el type submit del botón, pero si le quito el type submit no me hace la validación.

¿Cómo evito que se refresque la página?

> Formulario

```html
<form class="col-12 form" id="registration">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fecha Inicio:</label>
          <div class="input-group date" id="date-inicio" data-target-input="nearest">
              <input id="date-inicio" name="date-inicio" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#date-inicio"/>
              <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#date-inicio" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                  <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <!-- /.form group -->
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fecha Fin:</label>
          <div class="input-group date" id="date-fin" data-target-input="nearest">
              <input id="date-fin" name="date-fin" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#date-fin"/>
              <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#date-fin" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                  <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.form group -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 align-self-center" style="padding-top: 1.5%">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block bg-gradient-info"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Validación

```js
$(document).on('submit','#registration', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      getAllTicketsAjax();
    });

function getAllTicketsAjax() {

          var date_inicio = $("#date-inicio").find("input").val();
          var date_fin = $("#date-fin").find("input").val();

          if (date_inicio.length > 0 && date_fin.length == 0 || date_inicio.length == 0 && date_fin.length > 0) {
            $("#registration").validate({
                rules: {
                  "date-inicio": {
                    required: true
                  },
                  "date-fin": {
                    required: true
                  }

                },
                messages: {
                  "date-inicio": {
                    required: "We need your email address to contact you"
                  },
                  "date-fin": {
                    required: "We need your email address to contact you"
                  }

                },
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                  error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
                  element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
                },
                highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                  $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
                },
                unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                  $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
                }
            });
          } else {

            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('Tickets/getAllTicketsAjax')?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: {date_inicio:date_inicio, date_fin:date_fin},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                  $('#tabla_show_tickets').DataTable().destroy();
                  var html = '';
                  var comentarios = '';
                    var contador = 1;

                    var filas = data.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < filas; i++){ //cuenta la cantidad de registros
                        
                      if (data[i].id_attended === null || data[i].id_attended === '') {
                        comentarios = `<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="get_ticket_ajax('${data[i].id_ticket}')"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></a>
                                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" onclick="attendTicketAjax('${data[i].id_ticket}')"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></a>
                                        </div>`;
                      } else {
                        comentarios = `<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="get_ticket_ajax('${data[i].id_ticket}')"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></a>
                                        </div>`;
                      }
                        html += `<tr>
                                   <td>${contador}</td>
                                   <td>${data[i].request}</td>
                                   <td>${data[i].first_name}</td>
                                   <td><span class="tag tag-warning">${data[i].date_start}</span></td>
                                   <td><span class="tag tag-warning">${data[i].description}</span></td>
                                   <td>falta</td>
                                   <td class="text-right py-0 align-middle">
                                      ${comentarios}
                                   </td>
                                  </tr>`;

                        contador++;
                    }
                    $('#tbody_testimonial').html(html); 

                    $('#tabla_show_tickets').DataTable(); 
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("muy mal");
                }
            });

          }
        }
```

> Mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes añadir un evento al form en vez de utilizar la función y evitar su comportamiento por defecto.

```
$(document).on('submit','#registration', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var date_inicio = $("#date-inicio").find("input").val();
          var date_fin = $("#date-fin").find("input").val();

          if (date_inicio.length > 0 && date_fin.length == 0 || date_inicio.length == 0 && date_fin.length > 0) {
            $("#registration").validate({
                rules: {
                  "date-inicio": {
                    required: true
                  },
                  "date-fin": {
                    required: true
                  }

                },
                messages: {
                  "date-inicio": {
                    required: "We need your email address to contact you"
                  },
                  "date-fin": {
                    required: "We need your email address to contact you"
                  }

                },
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                  error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
                  element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
                },
                highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                  $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
                },
                unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                  $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
                }
            });
          } else {

            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('Tickets/getAllTicketsAjax')?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: {date_inicio:date_inicio, date_fin:date_fin},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                  $('#tabla_show_tickets').DataTable().destroy();
                  var html = '';
                  var comentarios = '';
                    var contador = 1;

                    var filas = data.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < filas; i++){ //cuenta la cantidad de registros
                        
                      if (data[i].id_attended === null || data[i].id_attended === '') {
                        comentarios = `<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="get_ticket_ajax('${data[i].id_ticket}')"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></a>
                                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" onclick="attendTicketAjax('${data[i].id_ticket}')"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></a>
                                        </div>`;
                      } else {
                        comentarios = `<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="get_ticket_ajax('${data[i].id_ticket}')"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></a>
                                        </div>`;
                      }
                        html += `<tr>
                                   <td>${contador}</td>
                                   <td>${data[i].request}</td>
                                   <td>${data[i].first_name}</td>
                                   <td><span class="tag tag-warning">${data[i].date_start}</span></td>
                                   <td><span class="tag tag-warning">${data[i].description}</span></td>
                                   <td>falta</td>
                                   <td class="text-right py-0 align-middle">
                                      ${comentarios}
                                   </td>
                                  </tr>`;

                        contador++;
                    }
                    $('#tbody_testimonial').html(html); 

                    $('#tabla_show_tickets').DataTable(); 
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("muy mal");
                }
            });

          }
        }
```

A tu botón hay que quitarle el **onclick**

```
<button type="submit" id="nc" class="btn btn-block bg-gradient-info"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
```

Comment: si quedo pero ve muestra el mensaje de validación de error cuando le doy 2 click al botón. No muestra el mensaje al primer click, lo muestra hasta el segundo click.

Comment: podrías actualizar el código, para saber como lo tienes ahora ?

Comment: Listo ya actualice el código

Comment: si haces debug, ¿en el primer click se mete a la función getAllTicketsAjax?

Comment: si entra, puse un alert al inicio función getAllTicketsAjax y despues presione boton y si lo mostro pero no mostró el mensaje

Comment: como haces la prueba con los inputs vacíos ? por que por el if que tienes, solo valida cuando 1 tiene la fecha y el otro no, pero si los dos están con la fecha o vacíos, pasa directamente a ejecutar el ajax

Comment: si entra al validate también pero por una extraña razón no pinta el mensaje.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110039/discussion-between-darkfrostnight-and-javier-fr).

Comment: lo que necesito es que cuando los 2 campos estén vacíos muestre todos los registros en la tabla, pero cuando 1 input este vació y el otro no si necesito validar que ambos estén llenos.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu boton de **submit** a **button**.

De esta manera...

```
<button type="button" id="nc" class="btn btn-block bg-gradient-info" onclick="getAllTicketsAjax()"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
```

Comment: ya lo hice y no aplica la validación

Comment: mejor dicho si hace la validación pero no me muestra el mensaje.

Comment: intenta eliminando el **#** del action

Comment: de echo el alert si aparece pero e mensaje que le asigne no aparece

Comment: ya hice de todo, incluso quite el # y no me sale mi mensaje

Comment: agregue una captura de pantalla del mensaje cuando el boton es submit, pero cuando lo pongo a button no lo muestra, si hace la validación supongo porque si muestra el alert pero el mensaje no

Comment: En la consola no te muestra algún error de envió?

Comment: No muestra error.